# How do I assign a String at Array1[x] to an int at Array2[x]?

Tags: string, file, parsing, sorting, object

I'm trying to organize data I am given from a text file, there are for 4 pieces of info on each line (City, country, population, and date). I wanted to have an array for each so I first put it all into one big String array and started to separate them into 4 arrays but I needed to change the Population info to an int array but it says *

> "Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type int to String"

```
//Separate the information by commas
    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        input = line.split(",");
            //Organize the data into 4 seperate arrays
            for(int x=0; x<input.length;x++){

                if(x%4==0){
                    cities[x] = input[x];
                }
                if(x%4==1){
                    countries[x] = input[x];    
                }
                if(x%4==2){
                    population[x] = Integer.parseInt(input[x]); 
                }
                if(x%4==3){
                    dates[x] = input[x];
                }

            }
    }
```

And when I print out the arrays they have a bunch of nulls in between each data. I'm planning to create objects that have the 4 pieces of data so that I can then sort them by population, dates etc... I'm pretty new to working with objects so if anyone has a better way of getting the 4 pieces of data into an object cause I haven't figured a way yet :/ My end goal was to have an array of these objects that I can u different sorting methods on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your x index. If you look carefully at your "for" you will see that it will insert a value at every 3 positions.

try

```
int index = 0;
 while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        input = line.split(",");
            //Organize the data into 4 seperate arrays
            for(int x=0; x<input.length;x++){

                if(x%4==0){
                    cities[index] = input[x];
                }
                if(x%4==1){
                    countries[index] = input[x];    
                }
                if(x%4==2){
                    population[index] = Integer.parseInt(input[x]); 
                }
                if(x%4==3){
                    dates[index] = input[x];
                }

            }
          ++index;
    }
```

Comment: This answers part of his question. But he really needs to create a class for this data instead of different arrays - because as it is there's no connection between the various "columns", so if he later sorts the population array, the population[0] value will no longer correspond to the cities[0] value etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
public class MyData {
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private Integer population;
    private String date;

    public MyData(String city, String, country, Integer population, String date) {
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.population = population;
        this.date = date;
    }

    // Add getters and setters here
}
```

And then in the file you're posting about:

```
...

ArrayList<MyData> allData = new ArrayList<MyData>();

while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String[] values = sc.nextLine().split(",");
    allData.add(new MyData(values[0], values[1], Integer.parseInt(values[2]), values[3]));
}

...
```

You need an object to store the data in so that you keep the relationship between the values in each column.

Also, I'm just assuming you're using Java here. Which language we're talking about is something you should include in your question or as a tag.

Comment: thanks! I already had the class set up but I didn't have the "this." in there, would that change anything? also ill make sure to put the language next time I post :)

Comment: The `this` isn't necessary unless there are other variables visible in the method with the same name, as there are in the method I wrote above. The `this` just tells Java that we're referring  to the object's properties and not the parameters of the method.